# How do I manipulate the last string of a Richtextbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, replace

I am trying to take a string in a rich text box and replace them with a different string.

Now how this should work is that if two same characters are entered into the text box 
e.g tt the "tt" will be replaced with "Ǿt" , it adds back one of the t's to the replaced string. Only the most recently entered string is manipulated if two same characters are entered .

I read the LAST string that is in the RichTextBox by using this method

`Dim laststring As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last`

`'hitting space bar breaks the operation so if i enter t t there will be no replacement`

this is the replacement method which I use , it works correctly .

```
        if laststring  = "tt"
        RichTextBox1 .Text = RichTextBox1 .Text.Replace("tt", "Ǿt")
```

This method is inefficient because i need to check id there are double letters for all letters and if i was to use this method it would tavke up a lot of code .

how can I accomplish this using a shorter method??

Comment: What if someone is editing in the middle of the box, rather than at the end?

Comment: i guess a find and replace function would be used for that .
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32793/RichTextBox-Control-with-Find-functionality)

and just replace the highlighted text .

What i'm doing  should only affect the last string only .

Comment: Can you define "last string"? Do you mean the last whitespace seperated word?

Comment: @JeffBridgman correct , the last word entered separated by a white space.
in the text "fundamental coding line"   line would be `laststring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `if then` section in a loop.

```
Dim holdstring As String
Dim doubleinstance() As String = {"bb", "tt", "uu"} '  array
Dim curstring As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last

For Each item As String In doubleinstance
    If RichTextBox1.Text.EndsWith(item) Then
        holdstring = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last.Length - 1 ' change to subtract 1 character from doubleinstance
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(curstring, "Ǿt" & holdstring)

        MsgBox(curstring)
    End If
Next item
```

Comment: I see , very good .
how would I then get `holdstring` to  be one of the characters from the the test entered .
for example : when i enter `bb` it should replace `bb` with Ǿtb
if i enter `uu` it should replace `uu` with Ǿtu

Comment: Take a look at the rich text box's `Select` and `SelectedText` members

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code to get you in the right direction...

There are a couple of variations of `.Find`, but you probably want to look at the `.Select` method.

```
    With RichTextBox1
        .Find("Don")
        .SelectedText = "Mr. Awesome"
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I came up with

```
        Dim holdstring As String
    Dim doubleinstance() As String = {"bb", "tt", "uu"} '  array
    Dim curstring As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last 
    If curstring = doubleinstance(0) And RichTextBox1.Text.EndsWith(doubleinstance(0)) Then
        holdstring = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last.Length - 1 ' change to subtract 1 character from doubleinstance
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(curstring, "Ǿt" + holdstring)

        MsgBox(curstring)
    End If
```

where i have `doubleinstance(0)` how do i get the if statement to not only check a single index but all of the index from 0 to 2 in this example ?